# Is phosphorine (C₅H₅P) aromatic?

Tags: aromatic-compounds, theoretical-chemistry, aromaticity, organophosphorus-compounds

Phophorine seems aromatic as it has 6 conjugated electrons. But the answer given is that it is not. This seems odd since pyridine has a similar structure and is also aromatic. Thus I ask is phospohrine aromatic or not?

[image]

Comment: [Phosphinine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphinine) *is* aromatic, but somewhat less than benzene.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Phosphorine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorine) (IUPAC: phosphinine) actually has aromatic character nearly as great (88%) as that of benzene.  According to the reference, phosphorine is sufficiently stable to be handled without air-free techniques; and it undergoes electrophilic substitution reactions similar to those of benzene.

Comment: With reference you mean the Wikipedia article? I have quite a bit of trouble believing this answer without knowing the context in which these 88% of aromatic character came about. Since there isn't even an agreed-upon rigorous definition of aromaticity, the number is without context equally as informative as a picked number from the phone book.

Comment: So ... you apparently think this is not aromatic?

Comment: No, that is not what I said. I just don't have any trust in that assessment of the 88% without any context of how this number came about.